# Socket interface

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sockets, mfc

I am working on the Visual C++ MFC based project. I developed a socket interface but there is some issue with it.  The message from client is delivered to server successfully and it can be shown in the dialog, but nothing is received at the client when server sends some message.

Server receives the message. But client doesnot receive.

What can be the solution for sending message to the client?

```
void CSockDlg::OnReceive(void)
{

    LPTSTR pBuf = new TCHAR[1025];
    int iBufSize = 1024, iRcvd;
    CString strRecvd;

    iRcvd = m_sConnectSocket.Receive(pBuf, iBufSize);


    if (iRcvd != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {    

        pBuf[iRcvd] = '\0';

        strRecvd = pBuf;

        m_ctlRecvd.AddString(strRecvd);

        UpdateData(FALSE);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your code so we can tell you where you went wrong?

Comment: @Nabeel Maybe there is something like a flush() function to be called to flush out an underlying buffer?

Comment: Which value returns Receive method? How your server replies?

Comment: Whenever this OnReceive function triggered, the message from the socket is retrieved.  Guys the message from client is successfully received to the server but not from server to client.

Comment: As far as I understood, presented code is a client part. Therefore my question was "iRcvd = m_sConnectSocket.Receive(pBuf, iBufSize);" which value does iRcvd have? And how does your server send?

Comment: I just debug my code again by making my interface to Server, The above Receive function works when from Server to Client  . Now should i add another receive function so that message can be recieved to the  Client?? When the code is client, it doesnt work.

Comment: After the server sends a response does it close the connection?

Comment: Close connection function doesnt call.